# PHP >> Date Period Foreach Won't run

Tags: php, datetime

Can't work out what I'm missing here, can anyone help?

This should be simple, GET `start_date` & `end_date`, create `DatePeriod()` with interval 1 day, loop through.

but it won't work for some reason?

URL which loads is:

```
/forms/process_table_cumulative_averages.php?start_date=12-05-2015&end_date=19-05-2015&team_id=all
```

Code is as follows:

```
$start_date = new DateTime();
$end_date = new DateTime();

$start_date->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['start_date']);
$end_date->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['end_date']);

$team_id = $_GET['team_id'];

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval, $end_date);

foreach ( $period as $datetime ){
    echo "hi\n";
}
```

Output is `204 No Content`

:( Thanks

Comment: The date you are passing in is in the format d-m-Y not d/m/Y.  Does changing that fix it or is it just a typo in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is a static function that returns DateTime instance, so you must assign the result to your start and end variables:

```
$start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $_GET['start_date']);
$end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $_GET['end_date']);
```

Comment: Legendary, nice one. Although for reference, it should be `d-m-Y` :)